# GIMP Gray borders Fill with BG Color in PDF exported file

Tags: gimp, pdf, borders

In GIMP I dont these see borders. The same when I export jpg or png. Only PDF give me these ugly borders.

I have selected area with the select tool,
then I clicked right mouse button->edit->fill with fg color.

There are probably borders of these filled layers. But it's visible only after export in PDF.

[image: Gray ugly borders in exported PDF]

Comment: What OS, what versions of all software, how are you making the PDF file, what are you then viewing it in? There is not enough information for us to even guess at.

Comment: What software are you using to view the PDF?  Try using Adobe Reader.  Also not sure why you are using GIMP for this.  It's a photo editor. Can't you just retype the text? Use something like Scribus if you are doing page layout, or you could even use Inkscape. These are both free and open source like GIMP.